# How to turn off Writefull on Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

Overleaf is perhaps the most popular Tex tool for the new-gen. How to turn off Writefull as the red icon on the top is really big, place-taking, and annoying.

[image]

Comment: That is a browser extension, you should be able to uninstall it from the Chrome Web Store (https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/writefull-for-overleaf/edhnemgfcihjcpfhkoiiejgedkbefnhg).

Comment: that is just your settings not anything added by overleaf or seen by most overleaf users

Comment: you can turn it off at the account setting page.